# asp.net multiple updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have multiple updatepanel in a page I want to update only 1 of them.
I use the doPostBack but I pass on each page_load and I dont know witch one I click.

so how can I get the doPostBack args

I tryied putting an hidden field on my panel but, I lose the data on the postback.

any help

tank you

Comment: what triggers the postback? The control that triggers the postback should be enough information.

Comment: look like this  __doPostBack('ctl00_......', 'panel0'); and I want to get the "panel0", so I can update only the right panel

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to determine which control caused the PostBack ([link](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx)).

Comment: my problem is all param seems empty. I get :   page.Request.Params.[Get]("__EVENTTARGET") ",,"

Comment: ",," is my get, I try to know why

Comment: I try your links, the GetPostBackControl, but return nothing